# PHP Array: Twice if statement in a for

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, oscommerce

I'm having a difficult to finish a if statement twice.. The rest works fine but when I try to check in another subarray it doesn't work.

**EDIT:** 
*- The first if condition is to check the type of products
- The second if condition is to check the size attributes.
- Products: sweatshirt_crianca and sweatshirtc_crianca_capuz 
- Sizes: 4_anos, 6_anos, 8_anos, 11_anos, 12_anos and 14_anos
Need to disable ( $this->enabled = false; ) Those sizes except 14_anos.*

This is what I get from **$order->products[$i]**

```
Array
(
    [qty] => 1
    [name] => .Mr Mickey T-shirt
    [model] => 
    [image] => blusa-mr-mrs-blusao-sweat-camisolas-portugal.png
    [tax] => 20
    [tax_description] => IVA 23%
    [price] => 10.8333
    [final_price] => 16.6666
    [weight] => 0.00
    [id] => 1342{18}135{17}132{19}148
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [option] => s_cor_produto
                    [value] => branco
                    [option_id] => 18
                    [value_id] => 135
                    [prefix] => +
                    [price] => 0.0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [option] => s_produto
                    [value] => sweatshirt_crianca
                    [option_id] => 17
                    [value_id] => 132
                    [prefix] => +
                    [price] => 5.8333
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [option] => s_tamanho_produto
                    [value] => 8_anos
                    [option_id] => 19
                    [value_id] => 148
                    [prefix] => +
                    [price] => 0.0000
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [qty] => 1
    [name] => Adivinha quem vai ser mama shirt
    [model] => 
    [image] => adivinha-quem-vai-ser-mama-tshirt-gravida.png
    [tax] => 20
    [tax_description] => IVA 23%
    [price] => 10.8333
    [final_price] => 10.8333
    [weight] => 0.00
    [id] => 1860{20}157{18}139{17}128{19}152
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [option] => s_cor_impressao
                    [value] => branco
                    [option_id] => 20
                    [value_id] => 157
                    [prefix] => +
                    [price] => 0.0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [option] => s_cor_produto
                    [value] => azul_royal
                    [option_id] => 18
                    [value_id] => 139
                    [prefix] => +
                    [price] => 0.0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [option] => s_produto
                    [value] => tshirt_mulher
                    [option_id] => 17
                    [value_id] => 128
                    [prefix] => +
                    [price] => 0.0000
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [option] => s_tamanho_produto
                    [value] => M
                    [option_id] => 19
                    [value_id] => 152
                    [prefix] => +
                    [price] => 0.0000
                )

        )

)
```

Sometimes it can contains 1 or 4 subarrays. This is cod payment from osCommerce, I'm trying to exclude specific products from this method based on the attributes of it.
This works fine in the first if statement to check the [value] but the lines that are commented the syntax is correct but it's not working. This is the code I got:

```
  for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($order->products); $i<$n; $i++) {
    if ($order->products[$i]['weight'] > '0.00') {
      $this->enabled = false;
    }
    if ( (isset($order->products[$i]['attributes'])) && (sizeof($order->products[$i]['attributes']) > 0) ) {
      for ($j=0, $n2=sizeof($order->products[$i]['attributes']); $j<$n2; $j++) {
        if ( ($order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['option'] == 's_produto') && ($order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['value'] == 'sweatshirt_crianca') ) {
          //if ( ($order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['option'] == 's_tamanho_produto') && ($order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['value'] == '14_anos') ) {
            $this->enabled = false;
          //}
        }
        else if ( ($order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['option'] == 's_produto') && ($order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['value'] == 'sweatshirtc_crianca_capuz') ) {
          //if ( ($order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['option'] == 's_tamanho_produto') && ($order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['value'] != '14_anos') ) {
            $this->enabled = false;
          //}
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Are those commented `if`s supposed to be inside the others? Because you are testing if A=B. Then if it is, you test if A=C. Of course it is not.

Comment: Well, it seems like none of these attributes will pass both of those conditions (once uncommented). Are you sure they are supposed to be nested like you have it?

Comment: your logic doesnt make sense. Maybe give us your logic in pseudocode so that we know what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: The first if condition is to check 2 specific type of products then the second condition is to check the size I got: 4, 6, 8, 11, 12 ,14. Allowing only '14_anos'.

Comment: @sidyll well first if check A=B works, but then I need to check if C=D (attribute for sizes of the respetive product) but it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with  your code is that you want  to test for different
array elements but you're doing it  while iterating one by one. The code
inside  the  `for`  loop  will  only see  the  current  element  on  the
iteration.  So  when you  nest  the  `if` statements,  you're  basically
testing if the **current** element is equal to something, and then if it
is you test if  this very same element is equal  to something else. This
logic will fail.

Since apparently  only the  `option` and `value`  keys are  important, I
suggest creating  another array with  those first. Then, you  can access
all  these properties  at once  -- and  not only  the current  attribute
inside an iterator.  For example, here is a  simplified attributes array
for your last example in the question:

```
$attributes = [
    s_cor_impressao   => 'branco'
    s_cor_produto     => 'azul_royal'
    s_produto         => 'tshirt_mulher'
    s_tamanho_produto => 'M'
];
```

To create  this easily and also  to simplify your code,  I suggest using
the [`foreach  ... as`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.  Also, you don't  need to check  if the
array has  items. If there are  no items, simply the  `foreach` won't be
executed at all. It is worth checking if it is set, like you did, if you
don't know in advance.  But another way is to just  skip directly to the
next  iteration  if it  is  not  set  with the  [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)  control
structure.

```
foreach ($order->products as $product) {
    if ($product['weight'] > 0)
        $this->enabled = false;

    if (!isset($product['attributes']) || !is_array($product['attributes']))
        continue;

    $attributes = [];
    foreach ($products['attributes'] as $attr)
        $attributes[ $attr['option'] ] = $attr['value'];

    # [tests]
}
```

Now, in the tests mark above you can do your tests like:

```
if ($attr['s_produto'] == 'sweatshirt_crianca' &&
    $attr['s_tamanho_produto'] == '14_anos') {
    # do something
    # $this->enabled = false;
} else if (...) {
    # do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidyll beat me to it but I was thinking along similar lines:

```
  // loop through each product
  foreach ( $order->products as $prod )
  {

        if($prod['weight'] > '0.00')
        {
                $this->enabled = false;
        }

        if( isset($prod['attributes']) && is_array($prod['attributes']) )
        {
                $matching_product_type_found = false;
                $matching_valid_size_found = false;

                foreach ( $prod['attributes'] as $attr )
                 {
                       if ( $attr['option'] == 's_produto' &&
                            ( $attr['value'] == 'sweatshirt_crianca' ||
                              $attr['value'] == 'sweatshirtc_crianca_capuz'
                            ) )
                          {
                            $matching_product_type_found = true;
                          }

                       if ( $attr['option'] == 's_tamanho_produto' && $attr['value'] == '14_anos' )
                          {
                            $matching_valid_size_found = true;
                          }
                 }


                if( $matching_product_type_found == true )
                {

                     $this->enabled = $matching_valid_size_found;

                }

        }

  }
```

Comment: I can't make it working.. I need to switch to another subarray, I got differents parameters, I've to switch between [option] => s_produto to [option] => s_tamanho_produto where it check if isn't [value] => 14_anos

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your loop using `foreach` to make it more readable and prone to less errors. Also, watch out for your comparisons (`==` vs. `===`). Try it in this manner:

```
foreach ($order->products as $product) {
    if ($product['weight'] > 0.00) {
        $this->enabled = false;
    }
    if (!empty($product['attributes'])) {
        foreach ($product['attributes'] as $attribute) {

            if ($attribute['option'] === 's_produto') {

                switch ($attribute['value']) {
                    case "sweatshirt_crianca" :
                        // .. do some code
                        break;
                    case "s_tamanho_produto" :
                        // .. do some code
                        break;
                    case "14_anos" :
                        // .. do some code
                        break;
                    case "something else" :
                        // .. do some code
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: s_tamanho_produto belongs to $order->products[$i]['attributes'][$j]['option']